# Frame JButton,ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i have a problem of my code because all i wanna do is to appear the textfield and in the bottom the button so i used:
`setLayout(new FlowLayout());` but i got an error so i decided to change into `getContenPane();` but only one will appear in my frame here is my code .

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Awe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextField c;
JButton b;
Container cont = getContentPane();

public Awe() {
    c = new JTextField(15);
    b = new JButton("Ok");
    c.addActionListener(this);
    cont.add(c);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    cont.add(b);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source == c) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Awe frm = new Awe();
    frm.setTitle("Enter Your Character");
    frm.setSize(300, 150);
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error that you got?

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting one component in your frame because its default layout is BorderLayout, and its default position is CENTER, and you can only put one component in the center.

Add the text field with `cont.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);`, and add the button with `cont.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`, and that should solve the immediate problem.

We can't help you with errors unless you tell us what they are, preferably with a stack trace and the code that produced them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a layout for your frame, so the components can be arranjed, instead of being positioned on top of each other.

In your constructor add, for example:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

And most important, read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Fully compilable, no errors:

```
public class Awe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextField c;
JButton b;
Container cont = getContentPane();

public Awe() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c = new JTextField(15);
    b = new JButton("Ok");
    c.addActionListener(this);
    cont.add(c);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    cont.add(b);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source == c) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Awe frm = new Awe();
    frm.setTitle("Enter Your Character");
    frm.setSize(300, 150);
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: You probably were setting the layout after adding the components, the example in my answer works, now you just have to read the link I posted and figure out what layout best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As @rcook answer, your default layout is `BorderLayout` which set's all components to `CENTER`.

Following are the ways you can do it:

Make a `JPanel`, add your components to `JPanel` then add `JPanel` to `cont` as:

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.add(c);
panel.add(b);
cont.add(panel);
```

---

**OR** you can just use a `FLOWLAYOUT` as:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

set this before adding any component to `cont`.

---

**OR** you can just position your components in `BorderLayout` as:

```
cont.add(c,BorderLayout.CENTER);
cont.add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

---

**Useful Links**

1. [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)
2. [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Answer (score 0):

the best way i always do is to use setBounds() methods

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

JButton okBtn = new JButton ("OK");
JTextField filed = new JTextField();

public Frame(){

super.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
super.setVisible(true);
super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
super.setResizable(false);

super.setLayout(null);
super.getContentPane().add(okBtn);
super.getContentPane().add(filed);

filed.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30);
okBtn.setBounds(10, 45, 70, 30);

super.validate();
}
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    new Frame();

}

}
```

and this the result

[image]